# Qt API to check if wifi is enabled/disabled

Tags: qt, qt5.12

Is there a way in Qt application framework to check if wifi is enabled? And does the way work for Android, iOS, macOS and Windows?

Note that I want to check if wifi is enabled or not. i don't bother if I have internet connectivity.

**Environment:**
Qt 5.12.x commercial version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate your [QNetworkInterface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html) instances (`QT+=network` in your .pro), and check the `type()` for a wireless interface, and also check the `flags()` to see if it is up and running. Example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QNetworkInterface>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    for(const QNetworkInterface& iface : QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces()) {
        if (iface.type() == QNetworkInterface::Wifi) {
            qDebug() << iface.humanReadableName() << "(" << iface.name() << ")"
                     << "is up:" << iface.flags().testFlag(QNetworkInterface::IsUp)
                     << "is running:" << iface.flags().testFlag(QNetworkInterface::IsRunning);
        }
    }
}
```

It should be cross-platform, but the documentation says that:

> Not all operating systems support reporting all features. Only the
>   IPv4 addresses are guaranteed to be listed by this class in all
>   platforms. In particular, IPv6 address listing is only supported on
>   Windows, Linux, macOS and the BSDs.

There is no word about other attributes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this